# How to make TortoiseSVN / TortoiseGit show the executed command?

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn, settings, tortoisegit

Tortoise GUI clients are cool, but they don't really help to understand, how versioning woks and what happens "behind the scenes". And understanding such things is very important, especially for Git. (OK, the best way is working on the command line...)

Is there a ssetting in ToroiseSVN / TortoiseGit to show the command that has just been executed? Or maybe a commands log?

Answer (score 14):

In TortoiseSVN you can enable this by enabling debug. If you Right-Click in your explorer and use TortoiseSVN -> Settings.

[image: TortoiseSVN -> Settings]

In the settings window, select Advanced, find the setting called Debug and set it to true. This will give you a popup with the command/s about to be executed just before you run them.

[image]

More about the advanced settings in TortoiseSVN: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-registry

Comment: The only change I notice when I turn on the Debug flag is that a dialog box is shown before each command is executed. However, that does not really show the literal svn command executed.

Answer (score 8):

The TortoiseSVN doc has a section "[Command Line Interface Cross Reference](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-cli.html)".

But don't forget the info box at the top:

> Even though there are CLI equivalents to what TortoiseSVN does, remember that TortoiseSVN does not call the CLI but uses the Subversion library directly.