# TortoiseGit show full command & parameters before performing action

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Is there a way to get TortoiseGit to show you the full command & parameters it is about to run before running it (just as it would be typed in Git Bash)?

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962054/how-to-make-tortoisesvn-tortoisegit-show-the-executed-command) about changing the debug setting, which will show you the command, and I can see the command & parameters that are run in the message screen after I run the command.

Does anyone know how to get TortoiseGit to show you this *before* you execute the command?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option and there [won't be](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/2401). TortoiseGit does not invoke git.exe for all operations, but also uses the [libgit2](/questions/tagged/libgit2) library.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out and thank you for your work on TortoiseGit.   Is this because the libgit2 API (https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD) do not map easily back to the command line and are not just wrappers of git.exe abilities?

Comment: Yeah, there are APIs of libgit2 which do not cleanly map to git.exe (sub) commansd. libgit2 does not call git.exe, but is a full reimplementation.