# Prevent TortoiseSVN from showing alert for every action

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am not sure how this happened, but lately my tortoiseSVN shows an alert for every single action I do, and will proceed only if I click on the alert box.

The alert box has a title of TortoiseProc. And the text in the alert is something similar to (Eg for SVN log):

```
/command:log /path "c:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject" /hwnd:0000000000025F9C
```

I read this SO question and some online forums as well, but I do not know what I should do in my TortoiseSVN to get rid of these annoying alerts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like at some point you enabled the debug option in the advanced settings:

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-registry

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19981416/1390430

It sounds like you don't actually want this enabled, so go into the "Advanced" section of the settings dialog and change the "Debug" setting to "false".

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!!! That was exactly what I was looking for! Your answer was to the point, and helpful. Wish I could thumbsup you twice!

Answer (score -3):

This is how TortoiseSVN works.

If you don't want GUI messages popping up from your command-line actions, use the appropriate commands with `svn.exe` instead.