# List of tortoisegit equivalents of command line commands?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm using TortoiseGit and going through some tutorials on Git, which of course all use the command line (for broad applicability).

Is there a list somewhere (my google-fu failed me) of this ?

Git Command >   TortoiseGit equivalent

Comment: First I would like to mention that I find the down voting here surprising to say the least. I also could not find and answer via google. I would be happy with a debug log of the executed git commands, but enabling debug seems not to do that either. Hence I use tortoiseGit only for showing logs and diffs. Other stuff I do on the git command line. I think this combination is optimal no matter if we find a translation or not.

Answer (score 1):

If do you want to the `TortoiseGit` command line, this is the page you need to:

1. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/git-command.html
2. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/
3. https://github.com/TortoiseGit/TortoiseGit

Answer (score 0):

There is no such kind of list. The reason is explained in the similar question and answer in this link:
[How to make TortoiseSVN / TortoiseGit show the executed command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962054/how-to-make-tortoisesvn-tortoisegit-show-the-executed-command/19981416)

Answer (score 0):

Here are available all TortoiseGit commands:

https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-automation.html